Trying to build an example of vtk's boolean difference operation using a sphere and a cylinder
I'm trying to learn how to use the vtk.BooleanOperationPolyDataFilter() to cut a hole through different shapes. The script below is an attempt to cut a cylinder-shaped hole through a cube. The cube is 10x10x10 while the cylinder has a radius of 1.0 and a height of 20.0. Unfortunately it throws a vtkPointLocator.cxx:868    ERR| vtkPointLocator (00000159CE2B6DF0): No points to subdivide error. And a vtkIntersectionPolyData:2410  WARN| No Intersection between objects warning. The warning implies the cube and cylinder are not intersecting, but I would have thought the cylinder is piercing through the cube like a bolt.
Any basic functioning example would do.
import vtk


cylinderSource = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
cylinderSource.SetResolution(50)
cylinderSource.SetRadius(1.0)
cylinderSource.SetHeight(20.0)
cylinderSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cylinderSource.Update()

cubeSource = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
cubeSource.SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
cubeSource.SetXLength(10)
cubeSource.SetYLength(10)
cubeSource.SetZLength(10)
cubeSource.Update()

cleanCylinder = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
cleanCylinder.SetInputConnection(cylinderSource.GetOutputPort())
cleanCylinder.Update()

cleanCube = vtk.vtkCleanPolyData()
cleanCube.SetInputConnection(cubeSource.GetOutputPort())
cleanCube.Update()

# Boolean operation filter
booleanOperation = vtk.vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter()
booleanOperation.SetOperationToDifference()
booleanOperation.SetInputData(0, cleanCube.GetOutput())
booleanOperation.SetInputData(1, cleanCylinder.GetOutput())
booleanOperation.Update()

booleanOperationMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
booleanOperationMapper.SetInputConnection(booleanOperation.GetOutputPort())
booleanOperationActor = vtk.vtkActor()
booleanOperationActor.SetMapper(booleanOperationMapper)

# Render
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.AddActor(booleanOperationActor)
renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)  # Background color dark blue
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderWindow.SetSize(800, 600)
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

# Initialize the interactor and start the rendering loop
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()


I have been struggling with same thing, and found that you need to use vtkTriangleFilter with these input sources.
Change the definition of cleanCylinder and cleanCube as follows:
cleanCylinder = vtk.vtkTriangleFilter()

cleanCube = vtk.vtkTriangleFilter()

and your program works.
